# How to force a "new row" for images aligned like a grid in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'll try a diagram before I jump into explaining this little contrived one.

MY AWESOME WEBSITE BANNER GOES IN A DIV ALONG THIS AREA NICELY...........

---

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] MENU-NOT-PAGE

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] MENU-NOT-PAGE

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] MENU-NOT-PAGE

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----]

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----]

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----]

So I have a dynamic ajax page, when you click on a link from "MENU-NOT-PAGE" area, it loads a page into the page area, which is everywhere you see images at the moment. As you can see, it ignores the menu, until it hits below, and starts filling out that area. I currently use the current CSS to serve up my images neatly in a "grid"

and the HTML for the curious

```css
.grids {
  float: left;
  padding: 1px;
  text-align: center;
}

#pagearea {
width: 100%;
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
padding: 0 10px;
}

#sidebar {z-index: 999; float:right; width:245px; padding: 20px 20px 0 30px; font-size:10px; position: relative;}
#sidebar a{ font-weight:bold; }
#sidebar h2 { margin:0; padding:0 0 20px 0; text-transform:uppercase; color:#000; font-size:18px;}
#main { float:left; background:url(images/menubackgroud.gif) no-repeat top right #fff; max-width: 100%;} /*set width:100% to stop sliding effect*/
#text { padding:5px; width: 1800px;}
```

```html
  <div id="pagearea">
    <div id="sidebar">
     <h2>Menu</h2>
     <div class="item"><a href="page1.php"><img src="images/menuimage1.jpg" alt=" " /></a>
     <span class="description">Click here to change page</span></div>
     <div class="item"><a href="page2.php"><img src="images/menuimage2.jpg" alt=" " /></a>
     <span class="description">Click here to move page</span>                                                      </div>         
    </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
         <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
       <div id="text" >
          <div class="grids">
                  <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
                 <p>This is an image</p>
             </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Now what I WANT to happen, is for the images to continue to align nicely as it does in the example above. I can confirm that the images "fit", as I had it "fit" before using A LOT of nbsp's for styling, but now it's not working with this CSS. I'll show a diagram of what it's currently doing below. Please forgive me for not having a live example, I don't like fiddling with ports for apache.

MY AWESOME WEBSITE BANNER GOES IN A DIV ALONG THIS AREA NICELY...........

---

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] MENU-NOT-PAGE

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] MENU-NOT-PAGE

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] MENU-NOT-PAGE

[-----Image-----]

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----]

[-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----] [-----Image-----]

Anyone can think of a solution to this? Is there a way to "force a break" in between div elements somehow? This is what I tried to do, using [br>'s in between the problem divs, but nothing.

Comment: is this your whole code? put your full code to get the clear idea please

Comment: Just float the menu-not-page to the right, that should do it.

Comment: I'm unfortunately already using float:right on the not-page area, I'll add what I think will be all the relevant CSS (I get in troubel for adding too much code a lot)

Comment: This is easy peazy with grid. Is that an option?

Comment: I'm not sure I guess I can't think of a reason it wouldn't be @Dejan.S  ?

Comment: Mainly browser support. You would have to figure the fallback to IE11 < yourself (Because I don't have time to do it all)

Comment: Oh no, my design has already "abandoned" support for anything before chrome, firefox IE11 so that's not a problem at all. I'll try to look into grids. It too me a long time to get this css to working lol

Comment: ffs the code snippet isn't running right this is why I spent this long doing the diagrams :( I hope you all can get enough of an idea at least

Comment: each one of those [-----Image-----] is a image?

Comment: yes they are my friend

Comment: I looked at a grid and I don't understand how to tell the grid to go from 4 images wide to 5 images after it drops below the menu area @Dejan.S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of big issues with your html. You don't close `<div id="text">`, also you use `id="text"` more then one time (ids are only once a page). You can solve this with this html and css.

```css
body {
  background-color: #333333;
}

#pagearea {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 100px);
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

.text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.text:nth-child(2n) {
    background-color: coral;
  }

.text:nth-child(3n) {
    background-color: lightgreen;
  }

#sidebar {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-column: 5;
  grid-row: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div id="pagearea">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <h2>Menu</h2>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="page1.php"><img src="images/menuimage1.jpg" alt=" " /></a>
      <span class="description">Click here to change page</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <a href="page2.php"><img src="images/menuimage2.jpg" alt=" " /></a>
      <span class="description">Click here to move page</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <div class="grids">
      <img src="/images/image.jpg" alt="">
      <p>This is an image</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Again, this seems drastic. I added clear:right to my current CSS and it almost fixed it except it put a blank white space and started at the bottom of the menu. Is there really no way to do a "line" break after (in the diagrams) the 12th image, to show that the NEXT image, the 13th, should start on a new line below, instead of trying to go next in the line which is causing the issue? Can't create a blank div that will create the line or anything? I don't understand this display:grid display:flex stuff, it does not fit into my current code at all and is almost bound to break other AJAX parts...

Comment: @Rogerjwilkinson I don't get how css will break your AJAX, but ok. If you provide the correct html I can have a look.

Comment: I found my quick and dirty fix. Check my submitted answer. I'm gonna tick yours as answered though since it provides a good general answer to the question (as evidenced by the code snippet) - What I meant by break my ajax is I didn't wnat this "fix" to have to take rewriting every page on my website, which with your proposed solution for MY problem, I think it would require (what happens to all the pages that fill up #pagearea that AREN'T images aligned in a grid, just plain text pages or w/e?) Great answer, too much work for my minor problem though.

Answer (score 0):

```
.grids {
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}
#grids {
    margin-bottom: 350px;
}
```

Refined answer even further (dropping the .grids2 class entirely). Wrap the first 12 images (sticking with the diagram example) in a div with id #grids, wrap all the ones after in a div named #grids2 (emphasis on this being their id, not class), and thenn apply the #grids css above, tweaking the margin as required (theoretically it should be the height of the image, but the number needs to be tweaked ever so slightly).

This was a "quick, dirty, effective" fix.